# Javascript Array solution

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional dynamic JSON array : example -

```
{
    "TEST": [{
        "_DocumentType": "INVOICE",
        "_DocumentDate": "2022-12-31",
        "_AccountNumber": "910:11:77:44520",
        "_DocumentNumber": "BILL-3270",
        "Detail": [{
                "test": "INVOICE",
                "test2": "2022-10-21"
            },
            {
                "test": "INVOICE",
                "test2": "2022-10-21"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "_DocumentType": "INVOICE",
        "_DocumentDate": "2022-12-31",
        "_AccountNumber": "910:11:77:44520",
        "_DocumentNumber": "BILL-2543",
        "Detail": [{
                "test": "INVOICE",
                "test2": "2022-12-31"
            },
            {
                "test": "INVOICE",
                "test2": "2022-12-31"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "_DocumentType": "INVOICE",
        "_DocumentDate": "2022-12-31",
        "_AccountNumber": "910:11:77:44520",
        "_DocumentNumber": "BILL-3270",
        "Detail": [{
                "test": "INVOICE",
                "test2": "2022-12-31"
            },
            {
                "test": "INVOICE",
                "test2": "2022-12-31"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

if _DocumentNumber are same in any array them combined with that if different _DocumentNumber then other array

Comment: That is not an array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to loop over your array of entries once and filter them down by unique `_DocumentNumber`. I'm using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in this example, storing the entire entry under the `DocuemtnNumber` key. If it does not exist yet, add it to the map, else look it up and merge the `Detail` properties using the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). The last step is to convert the Map back to an Array.

```js
const input = {
  TEST: [
    {
      _DocumentType: 'INVOICE',
      _DocumentDate: '2022-12-31',
      _AccountNumber: '910:11:77:44520',
      _DocumentNumber: 'BILL-3270',
      Detail: [
        {
          test: 'INVOICE',
          test2: '2022-10-21',
        },
        {
          test: 'INVOICE',
          test2: '2022-10-21',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      _DocumentType: 'INVOICE',
      _DocumentDate: '2022-12-31',
      _AccountNumber: '910:11:77:44520',
      _DocumentNumber: 'BILL-2543',
      Detail: [
        {
          test: 'INVOICE',
          test2: '2022-12-31',
        },
        {
          test: 'INVOICE',
          test2: '2022-12-31',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      _DocumentType: 'INVOICE',
      _DocumentDate: '2022-12-31',
      _AccountNumber: '910:11:77:44520',
      _DocumentNumber: 'BILL-3270',
      Detail: [
        {
          test: 'INVOICE',
          test2: '2022-12-31',
        },
        {
          test: 'INVOICE',
          test2: '2022-12-31',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const merged = Array.from(
  input.TEST.reduce((map, entry) => {
    const existingEntry = map.get(entry._DocumentNumber);

    if (!map.has(entry._DocumentNumber)) {
      map.set(entry._DocumentNumber, entry);
    } else {
      map.set(entry._DocumentNumber, {
        ...existingEntry,
        Detail: [...existingEntry.Detail, ...entry.Detail],
      });
    }

    return map;
  }, new Map()),
  ([_key, value]) => value,
);

// merged
// [
//   {
//     _DocumentType: 'INVOICE',
//     _DocumentDate: '2022-12-31',
//     _AccountNumber: '910:11:77:44520',
//     _DocumentNumber: 'BILL-3270',
//     Detail: [
//       {
//         test: 'INVOICE',
//         test2: '2022-10-21',
//       },
//       {
//         test: 'INVOICE',
//         test2: '2022-10-21',
//       },
//       {
//         test: 'INVOICE',
//         test2: '2022-12-31',
//       },
//       {
//         test: 'INVOICE',
//         test2: '2022-12-31',
//       },
//     ],
//   },
//   {
//     _DocumentType: 'INVOICE',
//     _DocumentDate: '2022-12-31',
//     _AccountNumber: '910:11:77:44520',
//     _DocumentNumber: 'BILL-2543',
//     Detail: [
//       {
//         test: 'INVOICE',
//         test2: '2022-12-31',
//       },
//       {
//         test: 'INVOICE',
//         test2: '2022-12-31',
//       },
//     ],
//   },
// ];
```